# how to align text to a corner of the screen

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with alot of items in the middle and I'd like to add to the page some small text up in the top left corner that says "You are logged in as *username*".  Any idea how to do this?

EDIT: My HTML page

```
<p style="position:fixed;top:0:right:0;color:blue" size="2">You are logged in as: {{ 
<body style="margin-left:100;margin-top:50">
    <table border="2">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Created By</th>
            <th>IP Range</th>
            <th>Date to Run</th>
        </tr>
        <form id="checkboxes" method="post" action="myurl">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkable" /></td>
                <td><a href="mysecondurl">name</a></td>
                <td>user</td>
                <td>ip</td>
                <td>time</td>
            </tr>

            <select id="dropdown">
                <option />
                <option value="Delete">Delete</option>
                <option value="Change">Change</option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="isDeleting" value="True"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Go" />
        </form>
    </table><br />
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'Minion.views.add' %}">
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'Minion.views.index' %}">
        <input type="hidden" name="loggingOut" value="True">
        <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
    </form>
</body>
```

This is with the suggestion given below, it just superimposes the username text over the title of the page.

Comment: Preparing a simple jsfiddle that demonstrates what you want might be appropriate to help you better.

Comment: A possible way is to use absolute positioning.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Would you like it all the way up against the edge of the browser window? Would you like it to scroll with the page?

Comment: I just want it stuck in the top-left corner

Answer (score 1):

It depends: The top left corner of what? The browser-window? In which case you could consider using `position: fixed` to stick it permanently to the top-left. Or just make it the very first item on your page.

Answer (score 0):

```
#userDiv {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
 }
```

You can have your text inside this div.